# Introducing a new assumption/hypothesis by adding it as subgoal

Tags: coq

Let's suppose that I have the following proof state:

```
1 subgoal
P, Q : Prop
H : P -> Q
-------------------(1/1)
Q
```

and I know a way to prove `P`, how may I add an "inline proof" of it so that I can have it in my  list of assumptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tactic `assert` does exactly that.

Using `assert (<proposition>)` breaks your objective into two subgoals, in the first you have to prove "`<proposition>`" with your current assumptions, and the second has your original goal as the objective, but with "`<proposition>`" added to the list of assumptions.

You may also specify its name with `assert (<proposition>) as <name>` or `assert (<name>: <proposition>)`.

---

Another option is to use `cut (<proposition>)`.

It also creates two objectives, one of the form `<proposition> -> <your objective>` (then you can get your hypothesis by using `intros`, or `intros <name>` if you want to specify its name), and another one in which you have to prove "`<prososition>`" with your current assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you can use is the [pose proof](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacv.pose-proof) tactic. This lets you actually supply the proof term and name it (`pose proof (foo bar baz) as qux` basically translates into `let qux := foo bar baz in ...` in the generated proof).

This can be neat for things like specialized versions of a lemma that you're going to use in multiple branches.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the SSRreflect proof language, you can use the `have proof_of_P: P. <write your proof here>` construct.